# How can I provide up to 70V AC power to a sliding glass door panel?

Tags: wiring

I'm renovating a master bath and the entire wall between the bath and the master is completely removed.  The view and light that this provides is very nice so I'm considering putting in glass instead of a solid (non-structural) wall that was there before.

The concern is privacy.  It's a master bath so in theory, it's not really a necessity but I think that would be awkward in practice especially with a clear glass shower stall.  Pattern glass or frosted/etched glass is another option but the SO and I are in complete disagreement on what would be appropriate.

The one option that would seem to allow us to have our cake and eat it too is using a switchable glass/film.  There are various manufacturers but here's an [example with some demo videos](https://shop.smarttint.com/Installation-Recomendations_bc_3.html).  There's actually a [video](https://player.vimeo.com/video/80220499) on the site where they show putting the film on what appears to be a sliding door and a ['sliding door package'](https://shop.smarttint.com/Smart-Tint-Sliding-Door-Package_p_15828.html) but I can't figure out what is getting power to the door.  There's a mention of a 'power transfer cable' but no picture or detailed description.

I think this is pretty straightforward for something that is fixed but we were planning to have a sliding door.  These products require a power source and it seems low voltage DC is **not** an option however the product above actually uses 60-70VAC power as pointed out by JPhi1618.  I had assumed these were DC powered.

Is there a proper, legit way to connect wiring for something like this?  It turns out all of these products run on AC as described in [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373488/pdlc-electrochromatic-film-switchable-glass).

Comment: Code doesn't have a lot to say about low-voltage wiring. You'll want to use a ribbon cable or something that's designed for repeated movement, but otherwise it's a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks. keywords are very helpful.

Comment: @isherwood Something like this: https://www.igus.com/chainflex/unharnessed-cable?

Comment: Take a look inside just about any household printer for what I meant. I don't know what's appropriate in your case, not being an industrial designer.

Comment: I'm imagining something like a tape measure that retracts but has a two conductor ribbon rather than a steel tape.  I wan't to use this on an exterior window to a bathroom, but at ~$1k for a large window it's still a bit pricy.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That's a possibility. I was also thinking like a track-light type system but with connections that are free to move.  Kind of like how street cars pick up power.  I'm guessing these kinds of systems aren't commercially available for residential purposes.

Comment: @JimmyJames, good news is that if no one comes up with a good answer, you can always make something yourself since it's low voltage.

Comment: Just want to add that I looked at the website you linked to and for them, "Low Voltage" is actually around 70VAC, so it's not line voltage, but it's high enough that you need to be a little more cautious.  I suspect its very low amperage, but I didn't find that spec.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks for the nudge.  This is all really nascent right now.  I know that it can be done with low voltage DC based on that they sell a license plate cover (only for car shows!) but I can't find that now.  Here's the more general [12V DC battery-operated page](https://shop.smarttint.com/Battery-Operated-Units_c_4764.html).

Comment: Right, but notice that transformer has an input of 12vdc and an output of 70v.  So either you have to get 70v to the door or mount the transformer on the door and get 12v to it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 You're totally right.  What a terrible website.  Could they make the text any smaller?

Comment: So, are you planning for it to be "always on" or only when the door is closed? If you set it up to switch "on" when closed, you could build that into a door switch with or without power, with pins, or as someone else said, with a ribbon cable. I know you said frosted/etched is out, but what about films? You could get patterns in colors or solids or frosted and "peel and stick". If you don't like, take it off and try a different one.

Comment: @JeffCates To level-set, the film is mostly clear when 'on' and obscured when the power is off.  The idea would be to keep it clear (on) most of the time.  It would be when privacy is desired that the switch would be off.  So I guess the door would be closed when the film is switched off.  If it worked the other way (clear when power is off), I like where you are going but I don't see that it helps much with how these actually work.

Comment: You just reverse the power switch in that case. Similar to that of an automotive door switch. When the door is closed, circuit is open (power disconnected, turned off.) When the door is open, the circuit is closed (power connected, turned on.)

Comment: @JeffCates I thought you were suggesting that the power would be connected by closing the door which would eliminate the need for some sort of flexible/movable power connection.  I've not gotten to how this would/could be switched yet.  Trying to determine the feasibility.  That the power is not actually DC or low voltage as pointed out by JPhi1618 has put me back to square one.

Comment: @JeffCates Though, perhaps having the power connect when fully opened might work.  Not sure about having a hot conductor exposed.  I'd have to think about how that might work.  I think 70VAC also puts me back into "what's code?" territory.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are in the US from your reference to 110VAC.  In Europe, the boundary for "extra-low voltage" (which is what regulators tend to get more relaxed about) is 50V, so you would be over that.  (Terminology note: to a power engineer, "mains" is "low voltage" - and so is three-phase.  You need to go to 1000V before it is "high voltage".)

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes all correct.  Here I mean 'low-voltage' as the term is used in US consumer products such as direct-bury yard wiring.

Comment: There is no such thing as a passive transformer that works on a DC input. if it is truly 12VDC in and 70VAC out, there must be a DC-A/C switching circuit somewhere. (Read that: active electronics). Not sure it makes a difference to any of the discussions here, but thought it should be pointed out. Are there safety concerns with 70VAC near water/shower?

Comment: @peinal Interesting question.  There would be 120VAC closer to water than this.  It's a little hypothetical at this point.  I decided against doing this for now anyway.